# How to get a return variable from a Python Script through JQuery?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, return

Currently I am trying to call a simple python script to test if I can receive output into my javascript function. However, when I do this ajax request

```
 function testPhy()
        {
            $.ajax({
              url: "./Phython/test.py",
              data: {param: text},
              success: function(dataR){
                  console.log("LK: " + dataR)
              },
              error: function(request, status, error) { 
              console.log("Error: " + error) 
              }
            });
        }


        testPhy();
```

I get the content's of the script and not the return variable

```
print("script running")
text = "Why hi there"
return text
```

Is there a way I can grab the contents of text from the python file using this Ajax query?

Comment: actualy the server just send the content of the file python, but you have to modify the server to run a python process and return the value..

Comment: your server is in php, python , C#, js...?

Comment: Currently I don't have a server running. Is there a way to do it without a server? @Frenchy

Comment: no, you cant do, because with client browser you cant access to local files (security)

Comment: So how would I set up a basic server? I don't need anything complex. I just need the return value

Comment: see my answer ist too diificult to put that in comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Server Node.js for example, i suggest you to read this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial/)

1- you create a basic server with a basic client web

2- use "child_process" package which comes packaged with node.

```
 const spawnpy = require("child_process").spawn;
 const pythonProcess = spawnpy('python',["path/script.py", arg1, arg2,  .and so on]);
```

3- To send data to node just do that in the python script:

```
     print(dataToSendToNode)
     sys.stdout.flush()
```

4- node server can listen for data using:

```
   pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      // Do something with the data returned from python script
   });
```

5- you answer to the ajax request (send data to your client browser)

You have lot of solutions to execute a python script with node.js, you could use python-shell, so when your server will be activa, search on google `python node.js` ...